# Ninject is specific about code order of constructors

Tags: c#, ninject

**Update**

I've managed to get around this. Now I check myself, whether the dependency can be resolved. If not, I'll look for a parameterless constructor (via Reflection) and call that. But I think this is Ninjects share of the work... so still more a workaround than a real solution.

**Original Question**

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(INavigationService asd)
    {
        // rnd stuff
    }

    public Test()
    {
        // other rnd stuff
    }
}
```

I've got this Test class. Now, I want two instances of it, created by Ninject. So I do the following:

```
Test test = Kernel.Get<Test>();
```

and run into an exception: "Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating INavigationService".

If I reorder the constructors like this

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        // other rnd stuff
    }

    public Test(INavigationService asd)
    {
        // rnd stuff
    }
}
```

it works.
But I can't be sure, that every class I use with Ninject has its constructors in "correct" order.
So, is there a way to tell Ninject to not ignore the parameterless constructor, if it's not the first one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ninject tries to inject the one with the most parameters (that it knows how to resolve*). However, you can tell Ninject explicitly which `constructor` to inject:

```
public class Test
{

    public Test(INavigationService asd)
    {
        // rnd stuff
    }

    [Inject]
    public Test()
    {
        // other rnd stuff
    }
}
```

**Note:** You cannot put `Inject` attribute on more than one constructor. It'll throw an exception.

**Update:**  Here's another way to tackle this, worth trying.

`Bind<ITest>().ToMethod(x => factoryMethod());`
`factoryMethod` does two things:

1. Checks if your dependency is loaded via `Kernel.CanResolve()` or some other way.
2. If yes, then use the parameterized `ctor`. If not, use the parameterless constructor.

Feels tacky and not sure if this is a good pattern to follow. If the parameters are optional, a better thing to do is use property injection (frowned upon generally) or method injection maybe.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I want Ninject to inject into both.
If it knows the INavigationService, it should use it. If not, it should use the other one, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: I see. Your question sounded different though. To do it cleanly, you probably have to wait a bit, take a look here: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/. Also suggest playing a bit with `WithConstructorArgument()`.

Comment: Thank you verry much, I'll look further into this!

Comment: Added some more suggestions. Do update with your final resolution, I'm curious.

Comment: +1 NB its not "with the most parameters" all over the docs, it says "with the most parameters that it knows how to resolve". While I'm not familiar with the code and the behavior exactly, I'd like to see this inconsistency in your answer resolved.

Comment: @Ruben: You're right about the doc but I don't know what it means *in practice*. Maybe it alludes to the `Inject` attribute but AFAIK, Ninject will attempt all the `ctor`s and if it finds two with same "number" of parameters, it'll throw an exception (even if it knows how to resolve at least one of them). And again, if it doesn't know how to resolve, it'll complain anyway!

Comment: @Mrchief: I've done some kind of workaround.
I didn't want to use facotries, as I want Ninject to do the work....
My ViewModelLocatorBase-Class now handels a bit more of this ViewModel resolving. I now check (after few condition) if the requested VM has parameterless constructor, and invoke this. But this is a mere workaround and not that satisfying.
Hopefully Ninject will fix this in the next version.

Comment: @Mrchief: The explicit marker taking precedence is clear in the docs. My point is that if you say it'll take the max and you have a ctor with 5 params and it prefers one with 3 that it understands (because it doesnt understand 4 of the 5) then your statement is in error. The only answer is a test (and I'm writing one for something else right now...!)